# Adding a dependencies in theme info file

Tags: 8, .info

Can I use dependencies[] = module name in the theme.info file? I want to create a drupal theme where I using some dependencies module, if I able to mention the dependencies in theme info it will easy to install the theme.

Comment: A **similar** question about module having dependency on themes can be found at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/101617/how-to-make-modules-depend-on-theme

Answer (score 9):

Nope, themes do not have such a directive in their info files.

Themes are supposed to be module independent. The "designed" way to do it is to move all module-dependent code to a custom module, and in relevant parts of your theme simply test for existence of data your custom module was supposed to provide.

Comment: A feature request is already created at https://drupal.org/node/474684 (for Drupal 8).