# How to make a theme depend on a module?

Tags: .info

My theme requires multiple modules to be install before it is fully functional. How can one set module dependency in a theme, so that when a user enables the theme, it will also enable the required modules? So far, I tried to specify the dependencies in the .info file of the theme, however, no success:

```
dependencies[] = some_module
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: A **similar** question about theme having dependency on modules can be found at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83152/adding-a-dependencies-in-theme-info-file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, this functionality doesn't exist yet (up to Drupal 7).

A feature request is already created at https://drupal.org/node/474684 (for Drupal 8).

Comment: And we don't expect it to be implemented as a theme should not depend on a module, as both have different purposes.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/474684 got in, so this is now possible for Drupal 8.9.0 version and later.  See the change record https://www.drupal.org/node/2937955

Answer (score 2):

This was introduced in Drupal **8.9.0**.

Quoting the change record https://www.drupal.org/node/2937955

> To declare a dependency in your theme you need to add it to the
> .info.yml file:
>
> ```
> name: test theme depending on nonexisting module
> type: theme
> core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
> dependencies:
>   - drupal:test_module_non_existing
> ```